# Using a Light Bulb Socket Switch to Control a Buzzer

Tags: light-fixture, safety

I am currently using a [turn knob switch](http://www.bigr.com/home-improvement-lighting-and-electrical-switches-outlets-and-plugs/cooper-wiring-3way-turnknob-intr-socket.htm) for light bulbs to enable and disable a buzzer. I think the buzzer runs at 12 volts and draws a few amps. Is this safe?

Unless I'm told otherwise my basic understanding is that at that voltage and current I am within the wattage range of typical bulbs. I'm open to being told I'm wrong.

Comment: Is the buzzer running on AC or DC? Most switches must be greatly derated in current for DC as there is no zero-crossing to stop the arc. If AC then OK; DC maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly safe. Lower wattage can always be put thru a switch capable of handling higher wattage.

Comment: +1 Safe, but not always functional. Some switches rely upon higher wattages running through them to function... which is why some timers fail on high efficiency led bulbs.

Comment: True, but since that wasn't the question being asked I decided to keep things simple.